# How do I use PYTHONIOENCODING environment variable to get past a unicode interpretation issue

Tags: python, encoding

I am trying to run a very short script in Python

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request




html = urllib.request.urlopen("http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/word?s=t").read().strip()
dhtml = str(html, "utf-8").strip()
soup = BeautifulSoup(dhtml.strip(), "html.parser")
```

I asked a similar question earlier, and this question has been created based on a respectable comment by J Sebastian on his answer. [Python program is running in IDLE but not in command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31494385/python-program-is-running-in-idle-but-not-in-command-line#comment51009142_31501696)

Is there a way to set the PythonIOEncoding earlier in either Github's Atom or Sublime Text 2 to automatically encode `soup.prettify()` to `utf-8`

I am going to run this program on a server (of course, the current portion is merely a quick test)

Answer (score 0):

`s=soup.prettify().encode('utf8')` makes it UTF-8 explicitly.

setting `PYTHONIOENCODING=utf8` in the shell and then `print(soup.prettify())` should use the specified encoding implicitly.